# Why pip freeze >requirements.txt return Permission denied

Tags: python, django, linux, virtualenv

When I worked in a virtual environment, I installed my packages `django-2.0` there. Yet it is installed globally:

```
sudo virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.5 ~/.virtualenv/venv
source ~/.virtualenv/venv/bin/activate
(venv) $ pip install django==2.0
```

And I had django-1.11 in my global environment before. However django-1.11 is also hoping to be installed into the other virtual environment, but it was also installed globally.
I uninstall this package, and try to install it into my virtual environ again.
but it seems like not work at all. All package installed newly were in global env.

Now i want to use `pip freeze >requirements.txt` to get requirements file,but it return :

```
(venv) $ pip3 freeze >requirements.txt
bash: requirements.txt: Permission denied
(venv) $ sudo pip3 freeze >requirements.txt
bash: requirements.txt: Permission denied
```

I thought maybe it was because that i install these package globally?I don't know.

How can i install package into my virtual environment correctly, and get requirement file:(

Comment: Re-read the error message: `bash: requirements.txt: Permission denied`. It's talking about `requirements.txt`, the file. It doesn't have _anything_ to do with pip. It just can't access the file.

Comment: Don't use sudo when creating the virtual environment. There should be no reason do to that. You also probably want to move into the directory created by your environment instead of the same directory as you're already in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a mere permission issue: check that requirements doesn't already exists with some permission you don't have. If so, `sudo rm requirements.txt` and `pip3 freeze > requirements.txt` should do the trick.

Else it should mean you don't have the write permission in the folder you are in. Try `sudo chown -R your_username directory_path`